# Упорядочить столбцы массива (матрицы) по значению их характеристик

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Имеются два массива  `mas1` - матрица с элементами и `characteristic` - одномерный массив с характеристикой каждого столбца массива `mas1`.

`size1Row` - количество строк

`size1Col` - количество столбцов

Те элемент `characteristic[0]` является "нейкой характеристикой" столбца `mas1[][0]`, элемент `characteristic[1]` является "нейкой характеристикой" столбца `mas1[][1]` и тд

Необходимо расположить столбцы в порядке возрастания их характеристик

```
void equivalentmas(int mas1[100][100], int characteristic[100], int size1Row, int size1Col) {
            
                for (int iCh = 0; iCh < size1Col; iCh++) {
                    if (characteristic[iCh] > characteristic[iCh + 1]) {
                        int temp_ch = characteristic[iCh];
                        characteristic[iCh] = characteristic[iCh + 1];
                        characteristic[iCh + 1] = temp_ch;
            
                        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < size1Row; iRow++) {
            
                            int temp_mas = mas1[iRow][iCh];
                            mas1[iRow][iCh] = mas1[iRow][iCh + 1];
                            mas1[iRow][iRow + 1] = temp_mas;
            
                        }
            
                    }
                }
            }
```

Это одна из функций кода, при надобности могу разместить весь с полным заданием.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем хранить "вес" или характеристику в другом массиве ? как вы будете ссылаться на нее в случае смены позиции при сортировке ?

Тут надо оперировать структурами с "весом" (характеристикa) и данными

как пример нужна структура по типу

```
struct obj
{
    int weigth;
    int *arr;
};
```

Теперь вы можете просто использовать qsort для сортировки

Пример с массивом 2х2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct obj
{
    int weigth;
    int *arr;
};

int comp(const obj *i, const obj *j)
{
    return i->weigth - j->weigth;
}

int main()
{
    obj mas1[2];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        mas1[i].arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            mas1[i].arr[j] = k++;
        }
        mas1[i].weigth = i;
    }
    // expm new weigth
    mas1[0].weigth = 1000;

    // print before sort
    for (int i{0}; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j{0}; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", mas1[i].arr[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    qsort(mas1, 2, sizeof(obj), (int (*)(const void *, const void *))comp);

    // print after sort
    for (int i{0}; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j{0}; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", mas1[i].arr[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        free(mas1[i].arr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```